# why it doesn't loop through the loop (JavaScript, Class, ShadowDOM, HTML Template tag)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web-component, shadow-dom

```js
      class Product extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
          let products = [
            { name: "carrot", price: "$ 6.99" },
            { name: "blueberry", price: "$ 6.99" }
          ];

          let pro = document.querySelector("#product_item").content;
          let copyHTML = document.importNode(pro, true);

          for (let product of products) {
            copyHTML.querySelector(".cerealName").textContent = product.name;
            this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
            this.shadowRoot.append(copyHTML.cloneNode(true));
          }
        }
      }
      customElements.define("product-item", Product);
```

```html
    <main>
      <product-item></product-item>
      <product-item></product-item>
    </main>

    <template id="product_item">
      <li class="cereal">
        <p class="cerealName" style="font-size: 3rem"></p>
      </li>
    </template>
```

I expected the result to be a

> carrot blueberry

But the result came with

> carrot carrot

I can't seem to run the loop, can you tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to call `attachShadow` once - after that it generates an error:

> Failed to execute 'attachShadow' on 'Element': Shadow root cannot be created on a host which already hosts a shadow tree.

You also only need one `<product-item>` element.

```js
      class Product extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
          let products = [
            { name: "carrot", price: "$ 6.99" },
            { name: "blueberry", price: "$ 6.99" }
          ];

          let pro = document.querySelector("#product_item").content;
          let copyHTML = document.importNode(pro, true);
          this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
          for (let product of products) {
            copyHTML.querySelector(".cerealName").textContent = product.name;
            this.shadowRoot.append(copyHTML.cloneNode(true));
          }
        }
      }
      customElements.define("product-item", Product);
```

```html
    <main>
      <product-item></product-item>
    </main>

    <template id="product_item">
      <li class="cereal">
        <span class="cerealName" style="font-size: 1.3rem"></span>
      </li>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

And you are also cloning the `<template>` **twice** with `importNode` and `cloneNode`

`cloneNode` is all you need, `importNode` is for importing from **other** documents.

And your component processed all `products` in **one** component; whilst you have multiple `<product-item>` in hour HTML

So I presume you want to make `<product-item>` display **one** product

I rewrote it a bit to (hopefully) let the code explain itself:

Note: the use of shadowDOM is probably overkill, it now blocks styling content.
Easily removed by removing 1 `.attachShadow(...)` and 3 `.shadowRoot` references.

```js
customElements.define("product-item", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let products = [{ name: "carrot", price: "6.99" },
                    { name: "blueberry", price: "6.99" }];

    let template = document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content;
    this.attachShadow({mode:"open"}).append(template.cloneNode(true));
    
    let product = products[this.getAttribute("nr")-1]; // UX starts at 1
    
    if (product) {
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("b").textContent = product.name;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("span").innerHTML = `  US$ ${product.price}`;
    } else {
      this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `No product`
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <product-item nr=1></product-item>
  <product-item nr=2></product-item>
  <product-item nr=3></product-item>
</ul>

<template id="PRODUCT-ITEM">
  <li class="product">
    <b>NAME</b><span>PRICE</span>
  </li>
</template>

<style>
  body {
    color: red; /* "Inheritable" CSS styles not blocked! */
  }
  .product { /* blocked by shadowDOM */
    color:green; 
  }
</style>
```

If you do want one `<my-products>` creating all HTML in one go; `innerHTML` is shorter and faster

```js
customElements.define("my-products", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    let products = [{ name: "carrot", price: "$ 6.99" },
                    { name: "blueberry", price: "$ 6.99" }];

    this
        //.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
        .innerHTML = products.map(product =>
          `<li class="product"><b>${product.name}</b> - ${product.price}</li>`
        ).join("");
  }
});
```

```html
<my-products></my-products>

<style>
  .product {
    color:green;
  }
</style>
```